# Instagram-api filters comments with 'gmail' emails inside

Tags: instagram-api

When I put a comment that is a GMail address like 'testemail@gmail.com' I can't read it with '/v1/media/{id}/comments' method. It's just filtered. Comments with any other emails (not GMail) are not filtered.

Why does it happen? I noticed that began when I switched from sandbox to production mode.

Comment: I tried this on my live app with API, seem to work for me, I was able to add gmail address and read via API, can you share a link to instagram photo that you saw the issue with?

Comment: I notices that Instagram just hides some comments. It seems it treats them as spam. Although I don't have any spam filters enabled.

Comment: ya, i know u cant comment the same message multiple times